# Websocket python flask update live template

Tags: python

i wan to update live a template using flask websocket IO. So bassic i have some message and for each one i wan to transfer it to the socket:

```
@socketio.on('message')
def handleMessage(msg):
   print('Message: ' + msg)
   emit(msg, broadcast=True)
```

`@app.route('/run_script/<script_name>')`

```
def run_script(script_name):
   path_to_file = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/files/" + script_name
    command = "python " + path_to_file
    process_handle = Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)

    while process_handle.poll() is None:
       for line in iter(process_handle.stdout.readline, ""):
           output = line.decode('utf-8')
           if output != '':
                print('Last message is: ' + output)
                handleMessage(output)
    return redirect("/admin/fileadmin/")
```

And the javascript looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000');

socket.on('connect', function() {
    socket.send('User has connected!');
});

socket.on('message', function(msg) {
    $("#messages").append('<li>'+msg+'</li>');
    console.log('Received message');
});

$('#sendbutton').on('click', function() {
    socket.send($('#myMessage').val());
    $('#myMessage').val('');
});
```

But every time i try to send a message i receive the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'namespace'
Can you help please?`[2018-08-23 21:37:51,855] ERROR in app: Exception on /run_script/TestScript.py [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "F:/SistemeInteligente/flask-admin/Training/file/app.py", line 49, in run_script
    handleMessage(output)
  File "F:/SistemeInteligente/flask-admin/Training/file/app.py", line 31, in handleMessage
    send(msg, broadcast=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 738, in send
    namespace = flask.request.namespace
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'namespace'
```

`

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: Thanks for you time